# Can a group be non-empty by definition of 'group'?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

By the definition of a group, "A group is a set combined with a binary operation".

By this definition, would a non-empty set constitute as being a group? By virtue of the definition of what a group is, a non-empty should constitute as being a group.

Can someone confirm?

Comment: That's not enough information to describe a group. You need to give a group operation on it too. It's true that groups must have nonempty underlying sets because they must have identities, but I don't think that's what you're asking. It's also true that every non-empty set can be given a group structure, but I also don't think that's what you're asking. Is it? Your question is not as clear as it could be.

Comment: Related: (The upshot is that, all nonempty set can be given a group structure) http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12973/does-every-non-empty-set-admit-a-group-structure-in-zf

Comment: Every group represents the symmetries of something, $X$ say. The empty set is not the symmetries of anything, because if the object $X$ had no symmetries then *that is a symmetry* - its group is the trivial group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because a requirement of a group is that there exists an identity element.

This alone prohibits the "empty group."